# How to edit or adjust images on Mac

Tags: macos

I need edit text that saved as file.jpg in my Macintosh computer.

For ex. I have file.jpg that have text: "One years production" and I would like to get rid from letter 's" left as "One year production".

I could not make any changes in jpg, so I've converted it to png.

I've used Tools-Rectangular Selection and take off the letter 's". Is it correct way to make editions or are the more efficient steps to follow to make some change in jpg or png files?

I am using pictures(jpg format) for my existing applications that written on JavaScript or Ruby. I would like to edit picture and put back to the existing frames.

How can I edit the existing pictures using my Mac to combine images as such?

I find some suggestion(see link below) but this suggestions is pretty old(5years); would be helpful to know some modern efficient way to edit pictures on Mac.

[How to combine two images into one on a Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52879/how-to-combine-two-images-into-one-on-a-mac?rq=1)

Comment: both are actually incorrect : how about "one year's production"

Comment: There seem to be several questions in here, please focus on one issue only (and ask separate questions for the rest). Also, are you looking for help in using a specific application (add the name then) or for tools suitable for editing?

Comment: Any text that shows on a .jpg or .png, as well as most bitmapped type images, isn't editable as if it was a text document. The text is overlaid on the original image and when saved/exported to .jpg or .png, is now a part of the overall image. Sure you can crop portions of the text, but it also removes the underlying image as well. A preferred way, is to use a copy of the original image that doesn't have text already on it and then use an app, e.g. GIMP, that can add the text as you want it. Some app image formats save the objects in layers that are editable, but not in  e.g. .jpg or .png type.

Comment: "one year's production" is fine. The question is the same: how to change existing  not correct spelling to the new one using Mac?

Comment: you wrote: "Also, are you looking for help in using a specific application (add the name then) or for tools suitable for editing?" Right now I would like to know how to edit the existing pictures using Mac.

Comment: you wrote: "Any text that shows on a .jpg or .png, as well as most bitmapped type images..." It mean that I could not edit existing images that safe in jpg and need to do from scratch? What software could you recommend if I want to edit, combine several images  on Mac?

Comment: In general, to edit a filie "using Mac" you would edit the file using a particular application on the Mac.  Perhaps Preview or GraphicConverter or GIMP or something else.

Comment: Could you provide the answer with some suggestion indicating what  advantages/disadvantage every software provided, like if   those options sufficient  for editing and/or free?  I've tried to use Preview but I could not see the option of combining several pictures.... You can get  point if you could help to figure out the editing software for Mac.

Comment: GIMP has been suggested, why don't you try it and report back?

Comment: Mike, I you could try and report as well. You good with grammar and probably make it quicker, I for once, need to use google  to know what is it - and it take some time:)

Comment: The current stable release of GIMP is 2.8.22 and was released on 2017-05-11, so I don't know where you're getting 5 years old from. [https://www.gimp.org/downloads/](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/)

Comment: I was refer to the answers about editing images(bottom of my question) - i don't know anything about GIMP(first time hear about it). Does somebody use it and could recommend in order to download and use it on mac? So far it was suggestion me to try. i like to be more sure before to try.

Answer (score 1):

I've used GIMP to combine 2 images on mac, following the procedure as below:

1. open both Images in Gimp
2. make the larger Image down to the smaller one
3. change canvas size to widthx2
4. open your other Image and copy visible
5. go back to your scaled layer and paste as new layer
6. select your alignment tool, click on move tool and move image.
7. merge visible layers and you got 2 combined images.